# How to set groupColumnShow to false when no data has been loaded into jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which initializes with no data, but then loads with data after some user interaction. My grid also uses the 'Grouping' features such that:

```js
ordersGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '',
    mtype: '',
    datatype: 'local',
    colNames: ['Order', 'Task #', 'Type', 'Status', 'Assignee', 'Current Location',
        'Dest Location', 'Change No', 'Net Patched', 'SAN Patched', 'Select'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Order', index: 'Order ID'},
        { name: 'Task #', index: 'Task #'},
        { name: 'Type', index: 'Type'},
        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status'},
        { name: 'Assignee', index: 'Assignee'},
        { name: 'Current Location', index: 'Current Location'},
        { name: 'Dest Location', index: 'Dest Location'},
        { name: 'Change No', index: 'Change No'},
        { name: 'Net Patched', index: 'Net Patched'},
        { name: 'SAN Patched', index: 'SAN Patched'},
        { name: 'Select', index: 'Select', width:'75px', classes: "SelectColumn",
            editable: true, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: {value:"True:False"},
            formatter:"checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled: false}}
    ],
    gridview: true,
    height: 'auto',
    pager: ordersGridPager,
    viewrecords: true,
    grouping: false, //Set to true once data is loaded.
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ['Order'],
        groupColumnShow: [false]
    },
    loadError: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

If I set the property 'grouping' to true during initialization of the grid I see the following error on the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stype' of undefined
```

This error doesn't exist if there is data on the grid before setting grouping to true. If I leave grouping as false everything is fine.

The problem is that I do not want to see my 'Order' column even when there is no data. How can I achieve this?

Here's a JS Fiddle with the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qrjZD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem which produced the error is the usage of `index` property in the `Order` column which value is not equal to the value of `name` property. In case of local grid (`datatype: 'local'`) you should never do this.

The next problem is that you used `name` property which contains special characters: spaces and `#`. It is not recommended because the name property will be used to constructs `id` attributes of some elements of the grid.

See the fixed code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qrjZD/3/.